# Is it possible to keep referenced files inside the service itself?

Tags: java, web-services, apache, file, jax-ws

I'm working on a jax-ws service in Eclipse. At some point, this service opens and uses a couple of XSLT stylesheets.

My question is, can you somehow import and keep these 2 files in the project itself, as you can with a library? For convenience' sake. I basically want my service to work as is, without having to go through the trouble of shipping the xslts along with the service but having to place them in different locations on the server, having to explain to people how and where they must go etc..

On a related note, how come when I make `new File("D:\x.xslt");`, the service looks for it in `"C:\Users\Tudor\Desktop\eclipseJ2EE\eclipse\D:\x.xslt"`? As in, `*eclipse_path*/*fileName*`. I would have understood, if it looked for the file in the root of the apache tomcat server; but not the installDir of eclipse... Anyway, how do I change that behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the xslt file within your source classpath and load it via the [Classloader](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29).

If you are using Spring you can also use the [ResourceLoader](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/ResourceLoader.html) to load resources.

Its rarely a good idea to use File instances with relative paths directly, since within different server environments the base directory often differs.

Hope this helps.